# How to name variables or arguments involving double plurals?

Tags: naming-conventions

As someone we know said that naming variables is one of the most complex software engineering problems..., it seems that you don't realise it until you face it.

Here is the current dilemma from a real life example: adding a CLI parameter that would allow user to specify in the format(s) of the file(s) generated as part of the test execution.

In most cases there is just one file generated in a single format but if it is possible to get multiple file and also to request multiple output format by using a command separated list of values, like `--controversial-param=junitxml,html`.

Based on names that went around, I came up to the impression that the winner will probably one that is matching this pattern:

```
--(output|report|result)[s]?-format[s]?
```

I argues against using a double plurals because they are grammatically incorrect.

The second reason against plurals (in general) was that they would cause confusions: it would be too easy for someone to add a parameter and forget to add the plural, pass the code review and fail after it was merged. I seen this kind of error many times in the past, even happened to me to do the "typo", or to miss it during the review process.

So I rely on others SO community to propose and vote *one* solution. Let the best argument win and use reasoning instead of personal preferences.

Comment: Does passing multiple values mean that all the output files will be generated in _all_ the formats specified? If so, in this case it's simpler than you think: `--output-formats` is perfectly fine, the word "output" can denote any amount of stuff, from nothing to one to many files, and "formats" can as well include zero or a single format.
There are other cases when double plurals would really be needed and the impossibility to use apostrophes can give you headaches.

Comment: @gbr please make that an answer!

Comment: here you are...                     .

Answer (score 0):

Based on popularity (google search results) and previous experience with other tools that I would propose

```
--output-format
```

No plurals at all, but will access a command separated list, this being  documented when using `--help`.

Answer (score 0):

If passing multiple values to your parameter mean that all the output files will be generated in all the formats specified, in this case it's simpler than you think:

`--output-formats` is perfectly fine, the word "*output*" can denote any amount of stuff, from nothing to one to many files, and "*formats*" can as well include zero or a single format.

There are other cases when double plurals would really be needed and the impossibility to use apostrophes can give you headaches